# Remove nth whitespace from string

Tags: r, string

I need to remove the nth whitespace from a string.

For example, here I would like to remove the 1st whitespace from
`my_string <- "this is a string"` so that it is now:

`"thisis a string"`

But I also need to be able to remove e.g., the second whitespace from the original to instead produce:

`"this isa string"`

How can I do this?

Comment: Basically you want a function `remove_nth_whitespace(string, n)` which removes the nth whitespace from the string, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function splits the string based on `" "`, pastes together the `n` and `n+1`'th elements of the split string and then pastes together the rest of the string without the `n+1` elements of the split string.

```
remove_n_ws = function(n, my_string) {  
    sub_str = unlist(strsplit(my_string, " "))
    sub_str[n] = paste(sub_str[n], sub_str[n+1], sep="")
    paste(sub_str[-c(n+1)], collapse=" ")
}
```

```
> remove_n_ws(1, my_string)
[1] "thisis a string"
> remove_n_ws(2, my_string)
[1] "this isa string"
> remove_n_ws(3, my_string)
[1] "this is astring"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option with `str_locate/str_sub` from `stringr` - get the start/end position index of all spaces with `str_locate_all`, then use `str_sub` to assign those locations to blank (`""`) and retrun the string

```
library(stringr)
remove_n_ws <- function(str1, n = 1) {
   
       loc <- str_locate_all(str1, "\\s+")[[1]][n,]
       str_sub(str1, loc[1], loc[2]) <- ""
       str1
}
```

-testing

```
> remove_n_ws(my_string, 1)
[1] "thisis a string"
> remove_n_ws(my_string, 2)
[1] "this isa string"
> remove_n_ws(my_string, 3)
[1] "this is astring"
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) Base R** Generate the regular expression using sprintf and then run it with sub.  No packages are used.

```
# input
n <- 2
string <- "this is a string"

s <- sprintf("((\\s+\\S+){%d})\\s+", n-1)
sub(s, "\\1", string)
## [1] "this isa string"
```

In the special case that n = 1 the above still works but we could alternately use just:

```
sub("\\s+", "", string)
## [1] "thisis a string"
```

**2) gsubfn** Using the same input we can use gsubfn. Define a proto object whose fun method returns "" if the count is n and returns its argument, the matched string, otherwise. This can be easily generalized.  For example if we wanted to remove the 2nd, 3rd and 4th instance then `if` could test `count %in% 2:4` instead.

```
library(gsubfn)

p <- proto(fun = function(., x) if (count == n) "" else x)
gsubfn("\\s+", p, string)
## [1] "this isa string"
```